# If statement in R error

Tags: r, if-statement

```
if(df$tfp_count > 50){

  mdlds <- lm(ltfp_sd~factor(country)+factor(year)+factor(sector),data=df)
  mdliqr<- lm(ltfp_iqr~factor(country)+factor(year)+factor(sector),data=df)
  sumds <- summary(mdlds)$coefficients
  sumdiqr <- summary(mdliqr)$coefficients
  }
```

I get this error:

```
In if (df$tfp_count > 50) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why doesn't my if-statement work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check `length(df$tfp_count)` - it's a vector with length greater than 1.

Comment: You are looking for a `ifelse()` function.

Comment: @csgillespie oh right! But then how would I make an if-statement where it uses all the elements instead of just the first?

Comment: Such as `all(df$tfp_count > 50)` or `any`

Answer (score 2):

If an if-statement is given a vector with length greater than one, it will only use the first element. The if-statment will still work, but only use the first element of the vector.

```
tst1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
tst2 <- c(FALSE, TRUE)

if (tst1) print("hello")
# [1] "hello"
# Warning message:
#   In if (tst1) print("hello") :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

if (tst2) print("hello") ## Will not print "hello"
# Warning message:
#   In if (tst1) print("hello") :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What you are receiving is a warning, not an error, but it is good to pay attention and ensure the behavior is as you would expect when you get a warning. If you want to "collapse" the conditional question, take a look at `?any` and `?all`.

```
if (any(tst2)) print("hello")
# [1] "hello"

if (all(tst1)) print("hello") ## will not print hello
```

To iterate over a vector and execute an if-statement, it would probably be best to create a loop. I would encourage you to wrap the if-statement in a function.

```
someFunc <- function(x) {
  if (x < 50) {
    "less"
  } else {
    "greater/equal"
  }
}

set.seed(1234)
input <- sample(100, 10)

## As a for-loop
res <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(input))
for (i in seq_along(input)) {
  res[i] <- someFunc(input[i])
}
res
# [1] "less"          "greater/equal" "greater/equal" "greater/equal"
# [5] "greater/equal" "greater/equal" "less"          "less"         
# [9] "greater/equal" "less"         


## The apply function apprach
sapply(input, someFunc)
# [1] "less"          "greater/equal" "greater/equal" "greater/equal"
# [5] "greater/equal" "greater/equal" "less"          "less"         
# [9] "greater/equal" "less"
```

Comment: So I want to run my script only where tfp_count is bigger than 50. Would I then use any like this: `if(any(df$tfp_count > 50)){...`

Comment: If you only want to run where `df$tfp_count` is less greater than 50, then just subset first. Something like: `df_sub <- df[df$tfp_count < 50, ]`, then do whatever calculations you want on the subset.

Comment: I would step back from your specific problem for a minute. Take some time to understand the code I provided so you can better understand how if-statements work, and why your attempt did not work. Then you can think about how you might solve your problem, either with a loop, or subsetting, or some combination of approaches.

Comment: so I wanted to use your apply function approach. However, when  I use `sapply(df$tfp_count, someFunc)` it gives me an error saying that there are missing values. So then I tried to do `sapply(df$tfp_count, someFunc, na.rm = FALSE)`, in order to try and ignore the missing values, unfortunately it says `unused argument na.rm = FALSE` when I try that...

Comment: If you need more help you will need to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If `df$tfp_count` has length greater than 1 (which it seems like it does) and all you care about is if any of the values in `df$tfp_count` are greater than 50 you could use this:

```
if(max(df$tfp_count) > 50){

  mdlds <- lm(ltfp_sd~factor(country)+factor(year)+factor(sector),data=df)
  mdliqr<- lm(ltfp_iqr~factor(country)+factor(year)+factor(sector),data=df)
  sumds <- summary(mdlds)$coefficients
  sumdiqr <- summary(mdliqr)$coefficients
  }
```

If you have `NA` values in your variable use `max(df$tfp_count,na.rm=T)`.